# Не могу залогинится после установки ROCm Version for AMD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd, radeon

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: после установки на мою ОС Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, драйвера для AMD Radeon [по этой инстуркции](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm), дошел до

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
```

после этого вышел из системы и хотел заново залогинится, но система **не дает залогинится** просто ввожу данные и система снова выбрасывает окно логин и пароль?
Так же при этом всем пытался установить *Radeon™ Software for Linux® version 18.20 for Ubuntu 18.04*, но постоянно выбрасывает ошибку...
Пытался залогинится в систему с помощью <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>  все норм работает, но в GUI оболочки ничего не работает!
Помогите ребята, как заново войти в систему?

Comment: Форматните диск и переустановите заново.

Comment: А получше ничего нет ?

Comment: Можно поставить Windows и (при необходимости) поставить бубунту на виртуалку.

Comment: Друзья помогите

Comment: Походу проблема в Кернел модуле во время загрузки системы убунту пытается загрузить драйвера для амд но их нету